# Symfony 2: The template should be a string or extend TemplateReference

Tags: symfony, twig

I have not found any significant help regarding the "The template should be a string or extend TemplateReference" in my Symfony2 project, so I am wondering if there is someone around, who came across the above issue.

Stack Trace:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The template should be a string or extend TemplateReference
at n/a
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/View/View.php line 178

at FOS\RestBundle\View\View->setTemplate(object(Template))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php line 128

at FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\ViewResponseListener->onKernelView(object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(array(object(ViewResponseListener), 'onKernelView'), object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 460

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\{closure}(object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1656

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(Closure)), 'kernel.view', object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1589

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1753

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 139

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', object(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2906

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2877

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3006

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2286

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /home/test/apps/test_admin/dev/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

**UPDATE**

I applied the following fix, but still no luck:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/commit/d2e9aaca8128bfcbd7cd0cb8a80ae34ab71b0c7e

Comment: What is the code triggering this error?

Comment: Cant be 100% sure, I am just accessing the {URL}/app_dev.php.

Comment: What is the code in the Controller?

Comment: I do not see something that can be helpful in the indexAction, which checks if the user is granted, and eventually does this:
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('hwi_oauth_connect'));

Comment: @thitami Post the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this one sorted out.
So, the issue was that my FOSRestBundle dependency was not up-to-date. Therefore, as soon as I updated it the problem got resolved.

Thanks all for your interest to help me. :)